# Microsoft Outlook Calendar 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

The dates for my calendar are reversed.  When I click on the arrow at the top to advance the month (from August to September) the month that comes up is July!  Can anyone give me inforamtion on how to change back the setting?

Comment: Does it always do this?  Did it ever work?  Have you tried anything (like rebooting, repairing Office, etc.)?

Comment: The view was correct up until about a month ago. Now, when I hit the arrow to forward the month it goes backward.  Yes, have restared the computer, but not repaired anything, not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird on for sure. :)

Perhaps try the [Office repair](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/detect-and-repair-applications-in-microsoft-office-2007/) features:

> Repair your Office programs by doing the following:
>
> 1. Click Start, then click Control Panel.
> 2. Click Programs and Features.
> 3. Click the Office program that you want to repair, then click Change.
> 4. Click Repair, then click Continue.
>
> You might need to restart your computer after the repair is complete.

You can also run the Office Diagnostics by going to `Start-->Programs-->Microsoft Office-->Microsoft Office Tools-->Microsoft Office Diagnostics`.

Comment: Can this be done for MS 2007 also?

Comment: Whoops, yeah, it'll work for 2007 as well. Sorry about that. :) I'll fix it.